# JavaScript: How can I get the number of USD bills from a given number?

Tags: javascript

I want to divide a given number into a set of bills (in USD) that it would take to add up to that number. Say, for example, I want to convert $1,833 USD into the bills it's made up of (for this example, we're not using $2 bills).

There's also a hard limit of ten bills of each type.

Going down each decimal place, that would be:

```
1000 = 10 $100 bills
800 = 10 $50 bills, 10 $20 bills, 10 $10 bills
30 = 6 $5 bills
3 = 3 $1 bills
```

Ideally, this should return an array with all of those values.

```
// Position 0 represents the number of $100 bills required and goes down to $1 in position 5.
[10, 10, 10, 10, 6, 3]
```

What's the best way to approach dividing up cash amounts like this?

**EDIT: Added that this example doesn't use $2 bills, and that this can only use a maximum of ten bills for each given amount.**

Comment: So, you don't have the right to use [$2 bills](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/00/USDnotesNew.png)?

Comment: I don't understand the logic, here. Why isn't $1883 = 180 * $100 + 1 * $50 + 1 * $20 + 1 * $10 + 3 * $1? How do you choose the bills?

Comment: Divide the total by 100, rounded down. That's how many $100s you need. Subtract that amount of money from the total. Repeat for 50s, 20s, 10s, 5s, 2s (yes they exist!) and 1s. Even works for coinage!

Comment: Have you tried looping through an array of bills using the floor() function?

Comment: Are there restrictions on how it must be broken up? For instance, $1833 could just be 1,833 $1 bills. In the example you give, it would be possible to get $800 from 10 $50 bills and 15 $20 bills, or many other combinations.

Comment: Do you want to optimize it for the fewest number of bills, so that 1,833 $1 bills isn't a valid solution? Because the example you gave isn't optimized that way.

Comment: It is a bit unclear how did you divided 800? Are you dividing equally?

Comment: Added some clarification. For this example, assume there's a hard limit of 10 bills per each denomination.

Comment: So all you do is loop over and calculate the bills needed using % and if over 10, do not use more than 10. Try to figure something out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple loop. You have know set of values you can use. You start with the biggest and work your way down to the lowest.

```js
var denominations = [100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1]

function makeChange (total) {
  // The stack of bills
  var piles = new Array(denominations.length).fill(0)
  // start with the largest
  var step = 0;
  // loop while we have money left or until we run out of bills
  while (total > 0 && step < denominations.length) {
    // get the first stack od=f money we can use to make change
    var denomination = denominations[step]
    // figure out how many bills we can use
    // if we have more than 10, only use 10
    var needed = Math.min(Math.floor(total / denomination), 10)
    // reduce the total by the bills we used
    total -= denomination * needed
    // update the stacks with the change
    piles[step] = needed
    // move to the next denomination in the array
    step++
  }
  // See if we were not able to make the change
  if (total > 0) {
    console.error("Still have money left:", total)
  }
  // return the piles of denominations
  return piles
}

console.log(makeChange(1833))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a dirty solution. But I got your answer

```js
let all = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
function traverse(amount) {
  if (amount / (100 * 10) > 1) {
    all[0] = all[0] + 10;
    traverse(amount - 100 * 10);
  } else if (amount / (50 * 10) > 1) {
    all[1] = all[1] + 10;
    traverse(amount - 50 * 10);
  } else if (amount / (20 * 10) > 1) {
    all[2] = all[2] + 10;
    traverse(amount - 20 * 10);
  } else if (amount / (10 * 10) > 1) {
    all[3] = all[3] + 10;
    traverse(amount - 10 * 10);
  } else if (amount / (10 * 10) > 1) {
    all[3] = all[3] + 10;
    traverse(amount - 10 * 10);
  } else {
    let fives = amount / 5;
    if (fives > 1) {
      all[4] = Math.floor(fives);
      traverse(amount - 5 * all[4]);
    } else {
      all[5] = Math.floor(amount);
    }
  }
}
traverse(1833);
console.log(all);
all = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
traverse(1848);
console.log(all);

// 1000 = 10 $100 bills
// 800 = 10 $50 bills, 10 $20 bills, 10 $10 bills
// 30 = 6 $5 bills
// 3 = 3 $1 bills
```